# How to create a swift generic variadic function?

Tags: swift, generics, variadic-functions

Here is my code

```
protocol P {}
class BaseClass {}
class AA: BaseClass, P {}
class BB: BaseClass {}
class CC: BaseClass, P {}


func test1<T>(value: T.Type...) where T: BaseClass & P {
}
```

Here we have 2 subclasses of BaseClass `AA` and `BB`.

`AA` and `CC` **conforms** to protocol `P`. `BB` **does not** conform to protocol `P`.

how do i use the function to only accept multiple parameters `AA` and `CC` but reject `BB` ?

I have tried this:

```
test(AA.self, BB.self)
```

This gives me a compile time error. Is there any way I can achieve the behavior above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way might be to declare a `typealias` for the pairing of `BaseClass` and `P`:

```
protocol P {}
class BaseClass {}
class AA: BaseClass, P {}
class BB: BaseClass {}
class CC: BaseClass, P {}

typealias BaseP = BaseClass & P
func test1(value: BaseP.Type...) {
    for t in value {
        print(t)
    }
}

test1(value: AA.self, CC.self) // prints "AA" and "CC"

// fails: "cannot convert value of type 'BB.Type' to expected argument type 'BaseP.Type' (aka '(BaseClass & P).Type')"
//test1(value: AA.self, BB.self)
```

Comment: or simply `func test(_ value: (BaseClass & P).Type...)  {`

Comment: ...its answers like this that makes me wonder why i wasted my entire day . Thanks a mil man.